# Resharper and VisualSvn shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, visualsvn

I've got an issue with VisualSvn shortcuts after instalation of resharper and choosing default reshaper key shortcuts scheme. It seems like resharper overrides all shortcuts and those that are not in scheme leaves blank. This includes VisualSvn shortcuts (All blank). I know that I can set theese in

Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard

But is there a way to apply all default visualsvn shortcuts without need to enter every shortcut manually?

Comment: Have you tried to repair VisualSVN installation though **Control Panel | Programs and Features**?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. ReSharper does not touch shortcuts of VisualSVN so far.